# ¿como cambiar el nombre de una propiedad en un array de objetos de manera incremental? Typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

espero puedan ayudarme se los agradecería mucho.

En un ejemplo como este:

```
productos: any = [{
    id: 'e101',
    producto: 'ravi'
  },
  {
    id: 'e102',
    producto: 'ram'
  },
  {
    id: 'e103',
    producto: 'rajesh'
  }];
```

¿Se puede cambiar el nombre de la propiedad de manera incremental?
Es decir, que quede de esta manera

```
    productos: any = [{
    id: 'e101',
    producto1: 'ravi'
  },
  {
    id: 'e102',
    producto2: 'ram'
  },
  {
    id: 'e103',
    producto3: 'rajesh'
  }];
```

Estaba intentando hacerlo con un map dentro de un foreach así:

```
let arreglado = resp.usuarios.map( item => { 
            return { nombre${index}: item.nombre , apellidoUsuario : item.apellido }; 
          });
```

pero este no me deja pasarle el index del foreach, si conocen como hacer esto o alguna otra forma de hacerlo se los agradecería mucho.

Muchas gracias por su ayuda !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
productos = [{
    id: 'e101',
    producto: 'ravi'
  },
  {
    id: 'e102',
    producto: 'ram'
  },
  {
    id: 'e103',
    producto: 'rajesh'
  }];
  

let arreglado =  productos.map( (p,i) => {
  
    // crear nueva propiedad de nombre producto{i + 1}
    p[`producto${i + 1}`] = p.producto;
    // remover la propiedad actual
    delete p.producto;
    // retornar el nuevo objeto
    return p;
  });
  
  
  console.log(productos);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias !